# Cannot see changes in TinyMCE plugin files

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to make some changes in the plugin files for tinyMCE.

For example I want the 'paste from word' dialog to be larger. 
I tried changing the `paste_dialog_width` and `paste_dialog_height` variables in the `editor_plugin.js` file from the paste folder.

But whatever I do, ctrl+F5, shift+F5, clearing all my cookies, sessions, everything, it looks like the changes aren't loaded.

Or am I changing the wrong file?

I also made an custom plugin. I changed the icon name `from example.gif` to `addmodule.gif` and changed this in the `editor_plugin.js`. But still the browser is searching for an `example.gif` file....

Some directions or tips are very welcome :)

Ow, and I use the compressed jquery version of tinyMCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Because I use the compressed version, tinyeMCE creates a .zip file everytime the editor loads (and the zip file doesn't exists) for faster loading of the editor. These held the old editor_plugin.js files and therefore didn't load my changes.

Removing the zip file (in the tinyMCE main folder) and refreshing the page will do the trick!